# Embedding image data in the contract of ERC20 compliant tokens?

Tags: tokens, erc-20

I've seen plenty of ERC20 token sales and ICOs lately, and a few sites have sprung up to track the value of various ERC20 compliant tokens. Most of these sites show images or logos associated with the tokens alongside the token ticker symbols. But as far as I know, these sites are just getting the images online or from the token creators to display on their sites.

I'm sure that it's possible store a tiny logo inside your token's contract, such that these sites could just grab the logo from the blockchain. It would probably cost a lot of gas depending on the resolution of the image, but it's theoretically possible.

So are any tokens that do this already, or is are there proposed additions to the ERC20 standard that includes the addition of tiny logo image data in the contracts?

Comment: Here's some information about how to do it with parity. https://medium.com/@Dave_Appleton/adding-an-image-to-your-token-on-parity-516fc8b51cab

Comment: 0.5 ETH is hella expensive for little more than advertising. I was actually thinking of putting emojis as the token ticker symbol. I assume Mist can handle it

Comment: I have made a terrible discovery. Emojis are considered an invalid UTF-8 sequence in Solidity v0.4.11.

Comment: If anybody is seriously considering this in 2021 or later it would be extremely expensive, but let's bring it up again as a new question because there are now new options for this (reducing from "woah" expensive to "hella" expensive).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, nor are there any proposals for adding image data into the ERC20 standard.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the image data to the contract but nobody yet will have a use for it externally. There has been no discussion to images, and the whole thing seems rather pointless with the ENS allowing you to alias an address, and thus maybe implement some for of favicon.ico.

There are a lot of discussions going on about ERC223 and other EIPs, but this seems like something best requested from ENS. The way it seems implemented now seems fine. Perhaps a favicon.ico project should stand on its own. The current address icon system is really lame.

Answer (score 0):

Example of an image in the Smart Contract:
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2799398.msg32974873#msg32974873
Gas price $0.7

Comment: Please add more information directly in this answer instead of simply linking to another site.

Comment: /// @param _message The message to be transferred (optional-0xbt)
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value, string _message) returns (bool success) {}
https://github.com/ZerroXBToken/zxbt

Answer (score 0):

Example of an image in the Smart Contract:
**/// @param _message The message to be transferred (optional-0xbt)**

*function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value, string _message) returns (bool success) {}*
https://github.com/ZerroXBToken/zxbt
https://youtu.be/4dRRFbVCWao